# Using markdown-parser in Angular

Tags: angular, markdown, angular6

i am using this [markdown-parser](https://markdown-it.github.io/markdown-it/) in my [angular6 app](https://stackblitz.com/github/raj2033/angular6-markdown-parser-demo). on giving input `# markdown-it rulezz!, **hi**` the expected output is it would be markdown, but in the browser, it is coming with the HTML tags.

[image]

Need help to understand where did i go wrong. thanks in advance

Comment: Your stackblitz sample doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes, i know. but not sure why. You can download the project in `local` and do npm install and ng serve. Then you could see it working as shown in output. but markdown is not coming up

Answer (score 0):

options:
html - false. Set true to enable HTML tags in source. Be careful! That's not safe! You may need external sanitizer to protect output from XSS. It's better to extend features via plugins, instead of enabling HTML.

```
var md = require('markdown-it')({
  html: true
});
```